# MessageContact Send "From Name"

Tags: rest-api, marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

Hopefully this is a quick one.

I would like to change the from name when sending an SMS via the MessageContact Send API facility. I.e. a name like "BRAND1" instead of assigned long code.

How do I best go about resolving this? Do I need to use SOAP API instead?

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation here and I'm not seeing any "From" setting. Do you need to use exacttarget for SMS? It seems there could be other AppExchange SMS apps that might fit your need? ( https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exacttarget.meta/exacttarget/node_2265.htm )

Answer (score 0):

**US ONLY INFO**

SMS messages are sent from a provider to a phone carrier, and therefore you have no way of controlling the name, same as if you dial someone's phone, they see numbers until they save you as a contact.

There is a `FromAddress` object in the SOAP API, however that is on an older product, and would use the new technology. It is also defined as:

> You can specify a From short code when you send an SMS message using
>   the API. You must specify a short code only when that short code is
>   not the default short code for the account. If multiple defaults are
>   defined within an account or if no default is defined in an account
>   with multiple short codes, the account deliberately leaves that
>   information undefined

In short, it's just specifying a particular short code in an account, and not the label the phone displays.

You are unable to change your long code into something more brand friendly.  If you come across something that reads otherwise, let me know.

**Edit**

The above is accurate for US sending, however the [docs](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/mobileconnect/mobileconnect_and_international_text_messages/) do explain how to do this outisde the US.

> MT messages sent outside the United States can include personalized alphanumeric From names 
>   (such as BRAND1) in place of a long code, allowing you to customize
>   your messages to subscribers. The MT recipients see the From name
>   instead of the long code from which the MT message was sent.
>
> - From names do not work for accounts in the United States, Canada, or Brazil.
> - From names must be configured for your account by ExactTarget at the account level.
> - Once configured, all MT messages sent from that account use the From name (this includes both triggered send and keyword responses).
> - All From names have a maximum limit of 11 characters.
>
> SMS recipients cannot respond to From names, as there is no long code
>   in the message to which to respond. Use From names for one-way
>   outbound communication only, such as alerts, updates, and
>   notifications. If you wish to receive a response, you must set up a
>   separate short code and include that number in the sent SMS message.
>   The recipient would then manually send a response to the specified
>   short code.

Based on this info, the From name wouldn't be set in the API call, but as it states at the account level.

Comment: Well they should absolutely not advertise this functionality if it's not supported. On here:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/mobileconnect/mobileconnect_and_international_text_messages/

From Names

MT messages sent outside the United States can include personalized alphanumeric From names (such as BRAND1) in place of a long code, allowing you to customize your messages to subscribers. The MT recipients see the From name instead of the long code from which the MT message was sent.

Comment: Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: @DanielCarrion - did this answer your question?  Make sure to mark it answered if yes. If not, let me know.

Comment: No it does not. I should be able to pass this as a Subscriber attribute.

Comment: That's not the functionality of the application. The documentation clearly states this. The question is answered for the app's current state, but you can add a suggestion using 3Sixty to request this functionality for future usage.